# Jquery return value

Tags: jquery

I try to get value from function

```
$.fn.find_place_for_dealer = function () {
    $(this).each(function (i, el) {
        var number = $(this).parent('.link-wrapper').prevAll('div.link-wrapper').length;
        var pos = ((parseInt(number/3) + 1) * 3) - 1;
        return pos;
    });
return $(this);
};

$('.dealers a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();     

    var pos = $(this).find_place_for_dealer();

    var el = '<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><div class="dealer-full-info"></div></div></div>';

    $('div.link-wrapper').eq(pos).after(el);        

});
```

but I get nothing.  What's wrong with my code and how can I fix it?
http://jsfiddle.net/EUcu4/4/

Comment: a jsfiddle would be better!

Comment: @Pavlo it seems you didn't see my html code at all

Comment: @Pavlo so your supposition was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use following snippet:

```
$.fn.find_place_for_dealer = function () {
    return this.each(function (i, el) {
        var number = $(this).parent('.link-wrapper').prevAll('div.link-wrapper').length;
        var pos = ((parseInt(number / 3) + 1) * 3) - 1;
        $(this).data('pos', pos);
    });
};
```

And then to get element `pos`:

```
var pos = $(this).find_place_for_dealer().data('pos');
```